# Save more than one user input into local storage

Tags: javascript, html, storage, local

I was wondering if someone could help me with local storage. I want to be able to store more than one user value into local storage and display them all individually so they can be used as buttons/links. Below there is some code that I've tried:

```
    locatArray = new Array();

    function save() {
        var fieldValue = document.getElementById("input").value;
        var locatItem = locatArray.push(fieldValue);

        localStorage.setItem("text", JSON.stringify(locatArray));
    }

    window.onload = function load() {
        var storedValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("text"));
        if(storedValue) {
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = (storedValue);
        }
```

This code allows a user to store more than one value in a key. However, as it is an array, when the page is refreshed and the user enters different data, the local storage values are overwritten. Also each value cannot be accessed individually.

I'm new to using local storage and I was wondering if someone could help me out.

Comment: You are playing with Key/Value pairs, sounds to me like you want to run temp tables in a database to better fit your needs

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your data not override it. Implement some synchronization mechanism that will first get data from localStorage and just push new item and store it again updated not override stored data.

If you want to remove some item do same thing. Get array from localStorage and just remove item you don't want anymore and store array in localStorage again.

**using your code:** `weather_urls` as key.

This will update your array stored in localStorage

```
function save() {
    var fieldValue = document.getElementById("input").value;

    var arrayOfLinks = localStorage.getItem("weather_urls");
    if(!arrayOfLinks){
        arrayOfLinks = []; // this is better way how to declare array not new Array()
    }
    arrayOfLinks.push(fieldValue);
    localStorage.setItem("weather_urls", arrayOfLinks);
}

window.onload = function load() {
    var storedValue = localStorage.getItem("weather_urls");
    if(storedValue) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = storedValue;
    }
```

Comment: The idea is to add locations for a weather app. The user will enter a location, it will be stored in local storage and displayed in a list whenever the user opens the web app. They will be able to click on the locations in the list to display the weather. How could I do this without predefined buttons?

Comment: you want to display all locoations at once? Do you want to be able to add,remove locations as needed? Do you need just links for weather or some additional information?

Comment: Yes I want it to display all locations at once and also allow the user to add and remove locations. I only need a link for the weather, no other data

Comment: I have changed my answer based on this discussion. So basically you need to implement some kind of synchronization. First get values and just add new to already existing values. Same thing for removing.